# Can't change a variable made outside a while loop inside the loop

Tags: java, loops, variables

```
public class Cow {
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Figure out a number between 1 and 100");
        int num = 4;
        int guess = scan.nextInt();
        if (guess == num) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it on your first try!");
        }
        int tries = 1;
        while (guess != num) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. You have guessed: " + tries 
                    + " times. Guess again!");
            tries++;
            int guess = scan.nextInt();     
        }
        System.out.println("You have figured it out in " + tries + " tries.");}
    }
}
```

I created a variable called guess outside the while loop. When I try to change guess inside of the loop, it says that guess is a "duplicate local variable".

Comment: Your problem is the `int` in front of `int` guess = scan.nextInt();

Comment: You no need to declare `guess` again in your loop. just `guess = scan.nextInt();` in your loop.

Answer (score 4):

It says "duplicate variable" because you declared it twice:

```
int guess = scan.nextInt();
//...
while (guess != num) {
    //...
    int guess = scan.nextInt();     
}
```

Remove the modifier:

```
int guess = scan.nextInt();
//...
while (guess != num) {
    //...
    guess = scan.nextInt();     
}
```

Potentially an easier solution altogether:

```
int guess;
while ((guess = scan.nextInt()) != num) {
    //do code
}
```

Comment: That was helpful. It says I'm supposed to avoid saying thanks, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3862880 not a problem!

Answer (score 0):

It *does* have a duplicate local variable. Here it is:

```
int guess = scan.nextInt();
```

Change this to:

```
guess = scan.nextInt();
```

And it will work.

### What was wrong?

When you have a type name in front of a variable (e.g. `int guess` or `Object foo`), that is a declaration in Java. And it will hide a previous declaration. See the below example:

```
int guess = 0; // we declare an int, named guess, and at the same time initialize it

for (...) { // with this curly braces, a new local scope starts
    // NOTE: in fact, curly braces start a new scope. the curly braces could be
    // there on it's own too. it does not have to be associated with a 
    // 'for', or a 'while', or a 'do-while', or an 'if'
    guess = 5; // this refers to the variable outside the scope, and overwrites it.

    // here be dragons!
    int guess = 2; // we're declaring an int, named 'guess' again. this will hide the former.
    guess = 8; // this refers to the locally declared variable, as the former one is hidden by it now
}

System.out.println(guess); // should print 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `guess` outside of the loop already (`int guess = scan.nextInt();`). You're trying to declare it again inside the loop, thus you are getting the message for "duplicate local variable."

You should remove the declaration **inside** the loop so that your loop looks like this:

```
        int guess = scan.nextInt();
        // ...
        while (guess != num) {
            // ...
            tries++;
            guess = scan.nextInt();
        }
        // ...
```